# How can I remove POS Tags in pythons and print the tree preserving subtree orders

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I am pretty new to python and need help on the following.
I have a string of the format:

(S Silver/RB (Chunk 42/CD inch/NN) LED/NNP HD/NNP Nakamichi/NNP Smart/NNP Flat/NNP (Chunk 3D/CD TV/NN))

The output I want:
Silver , 42 inch, LED , Nakamichi, Smart, Flat , 3D TV

Basically I want to preserve the subtree as a single string while printing it.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should only post to SO with some code you tried yourself, so we can see you made any effort to solve your own problem. Getting help in state you shown is just a good will of people, but probably your post is gonna just be downvoted.

Anyways, the pattern you've shown here doesn't seem to obey any rule, as, for example, 'Silver' part has the '/RB' string stripped from it and '42 inch' element from output has not only to strip other strings, that are '/CD' and '/NN', but should also be connected as one string. Unless you just messed up your commas and you want a single string (not a list, as it seems with what you have posted), then:

```
text = '(S Silver/RB (Chunk 42/CD inch/NN) LED/NNP HD/NNP Nakamichi/NNP Smart/NNP Flat/NNP (Chunk 3D/CD TV/NN))'
split_text = text.split(' ')
new_text = ''
for item in split_text:
    if item[0].isnumeric():
        new_text += item[:item.find('/')] + ' '
    elif item[0] == '(':
        pass
    else:
        new_text += item[:item.find('/')] + ' , '
new_text = new_text[:-3]
new_text
```

Output:

```
'Silver , 42 inch , LED , HD , Nakamichi , Smart , Flat , 3D TV'
```

Still there is little point to do that as the string is short and there are no regular patterns in it (unless, as I said, you messed up with showing what you really want).

Comment: Thanks for reponding Sqoshu.The string I mentioned is basically a tree with two subtrees. The output which you showed obtained using print(tree.leaves())                                                                                  
But what I want is something of the below format:                                          "Silver , 42 inch , LED , HD , Nakamichi , Smart , Flat , 3D TV "                        Here I want that the leaves of the subtrees should be together. I also tried using this pattern = r'\w+:?(?=\/)' and using re.findall , but it is giving me the same answer you posted

Comment: Check the edit. Have in mind this method is highly specific to just this case, not to every one you might want to use it with.

Comment: Really thanks for your help. This works perfectly fine.